# Refreshing a page when user input is wrong

Tags: javascript, forms, refresh

How can i reload/refresh a form when user input's wrong as am generating form dynamically, I managed to display a warning message but having problem resetting the field, also suggest any improvements needed in my code?

...

```
JavaScript: 
    
    const div = document.querySelector(".addHere");
    
    document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", addInputs);
    
    function addInputs() {
    
    const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
    
      if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
        alert("Wrong input");

          const form = document.createElement("form");
          form.method = "post";
          form.action = "#";

      } else {
        for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
    
          const input1 = document.createElement("input");
          input1.type = "text";
          input1.maxLength = "12";
          input1.className = "factor";
          input1.required = true;
    
          const input2 = document.createElement("input");
          input2.type = "text";
          input2.maxLength = "1";
          input2.className = "priority";
          input2.required = true;
    
          const br = document.createElement("br");
    
          form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
          form.appendChild(input1);
          form.appendChild(input2);
          form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    
          div.appendChild(form);
        }
    
        const sub = document.createElement("button");
        sub.type = "submit";
        sub.value = "Submit";
        sub.className = "subButton";
        sub.textContent = "Submit";
    
        div.appendChild(sub);
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="addHere"></div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the whole form's inputs to their original values like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('myform').reset();
</script>
```

Or only one input element like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('userName').value = '';
</script>
```

And if you want to reload the whole page, you should do this:

```
<script>
    document.location.href = document.location.href;
</script>
```

```
<form id="myform">

    <input id="userName" type="text" />

</form>
```

How about this?

CCS:

```
    <style>
        .subButton {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Script:

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            document.querySelector(".btnAdd").addEventListener("click", addInputs);
        });

        function addInputs() {
            const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".inputValue").value);
            if (isNaN(inputValue) || inputValue < 1) {
                alert("Wrong input");
                document.querySelector(".inputValue").value = '';
            } else {
                let html = '';
                for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i++) {
                    html += '<input type="text" maxlength="12" class="factor" required>';
                    html += '<input type="text" maxlength="1" class="priority" required>';
                    html += '<br />';
                }
                document.querySelector(".addHere").innerHTML = html;
                document.querySelector(".subButton").style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector(".inputs").style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <div class="addHere"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="subButton" />
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputValue" placeholder="insert numbers:" />
            <button type="button" class="btnAdd">+</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this single line

```js
document.getElementById('input').value = "";
```